# How can I add a responsive triangle/slant at the bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

For a project i've just been given to build there are several divs that need to have an angle to them at the bottom (such as in the image provided). Bearing in mind these divs need to be responsive and I also need to be able to set the colour and opacity dynamically (ruling out using a background image) can anyone assist me with the best way of doing this please? I've tried messing around with borders but thats not ideal as you can't use %'s for border thicknesses/widths and i've tried using :after with a transform:rotate(5deg) skew(5deg) property but this wasn't ideal either particularly when I needed opacity on the div as you could see the overlay.

If anyone knows of a nice way to do this please feel free to suggest. Thanks for your help :-)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUQe2.png)

Comment: Please add ur code here so that it can be modified

Comment: Few links on guides: 1) https://codepen.io/ahmadnassri/post/non-rectangular-headers-part-1 2) https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `background:linear-gradient();` property

CSS

```
.demo{
  height:200px;
  background: linear-gradient(-186deg,#ffa303 50%,transparent 10%);
  color:#fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="demo">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam iusto ad excepturi at iste ipsa nulla ipsum earum, enim possimus ab, modi perspiciatis fugit eaque accusantium atque repellat blanditiis praesentium.
</div>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/ce6rtrjn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linear gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(241, 143,41, 0.7) 84.9%, transparent 85%), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200) no-repeat;
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vw;
  background: linear-gradient(172deg, rgba(241, 143,41, 0.7) 84.9%, transparent 85%), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.triangle-box {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .5);
}
.triangle-box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .5);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 50%);
}
.triangle-box p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec elementum sem. Suspendisse bibendum ac massa eu faucibus.</p>
</div>
```